# Run out of memory in cython

Tags: memory-management, cython

I am trying to implement an algorithm in cython. But I am running out of memory on my `BitSet` implementation. I have no idea why, here are the useful snapshots of my code.

bitset.pyx

```py
# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.vector cimport vector


cdef class BitSet:

    def __cinit__(self, int size):
        self.vector = vector[bint](size)

    cpdef void inter(self, BitSet other) except *:
        # Do the intersection in place between two bitset

    cpdef void add(self, int element):
        if 0 <= element < self.vector.size():
            self.vector[element] = True
```

bitset.pxd

```py
# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.vector cimport vector


cdef class BitSet:
    cdef public vector[bint] vector
    cpdef void inter(self, BitSet other) except *
    cpdef void add(self, int element)
```

I need to create a python `list` of `BitSet` (around 12_000), each of size 1_000_000. I would say this is supposed to take 1_000_000 bits (to store bint type) * 12000 = 1.5 GB

But I am running out of memory very fast, here is a picture to explain more

[image]

The lowest point of the curve is at 1.5 GB and the highest is at 7 GB.

I am calling this program with a huge list of list, which might explain the first peak, the second one is probably the one I am facing.

My program runs out of memory after only 100_000 sequences.

Here is my main :

```py
cdef class Main:
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.number_sequences # Int
        self.foo = [] # python list type

    def train(self, sequences):
        self.number_sequences = len(sequences)
        for id_seq, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
            for element in sequence:
                while not element < len(self.foo):
                    self.foo.append(BitSet(self.number_sequences))
                self.foo[element].add(id_seq)
```

Is my estimation of memory use wrong? And why?

How can I trace my memory? I did not find any tools for cython.

Is there any solution to make it fit in memory? (Replacing BitSet by python set of ints work, but it is much slower and should take more space)

Comment: `bint` will be (at least) a byte rather than a bit. You might be better with the C++ [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), but I don't think Cython has a pre-written wrapper, or alternatively the optimised `std::vector<bool>`, although I'm not 100% sure of the status of that

Comment: I did not know for the bint. It might explain à lot of things. How did you know that?

Comment: You can test it (rather than trusting me) by `print(sizeof(bint))`. Essentially any variable in C/C++ has to take up at least a byte. Any more efficient scheme will store `uint8_t`s (or similar) and then access individual bits of those - this is what `bitset` and `vector<bool>` do, but at a small speed cost

Comment: ....Although remember that `sizeof` returns an answer in bytes (which is kind of a clue that the size of everything must be in whole bytes)

Comment: After investigation, a bint is stored on 4 Bytes and not 1/8B. Which multiplies it by 32.
If you write an answer @DavidW I might accept it, I will otpimize my code using uint8_t ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bint` is just a convenient integer type that can be used to store a true/false value. In common with all other C types it needs to have an address that can be measured in whole bytes, and so it takes up at least 1 bytes (in practice it looks like more).

In order store bools in a space efficient way you need to store integer types and then do some bit twiddling to access individual elements:

```
cdef uint8_t x = some_value
nth_element_is_true = bool(x & (1<<n)) # bitshift to get a suitable mask then bitwise and
```

You can obviously extend this to use arrays to store multiple elements.

---

A few obvious pre-made possibilities exist:

First you could use `numpy.packbits` and `unpackbits`. This do generate reasonably expensive temporary variables (e.g. `unpackbits` will create an array 8 times the size) though.

Second you could use `std::vector<bool>` which is already optimized to use 1-bit per element:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp cimport bool
cdef vector[bool] vb = vector[bool](1000000)
```

The creation of a specialized `vector<bool>` that doesn't *quite* behave the same as a normal `vector` is considered a bad idea in hindsight in C++, but it does what you want.